# Possibility of accessing 3rd party application's data from android-room

Tags: android, android-room

Is it possible to access data of 3rd party applications stored in Room database if they are not explicitly using `ContentProvider` to share the data? If not what is enforcing me not to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to access data of 3rd party applications stored in Room database if they are not explicitly using ContentProvider to share the data?

Not usually. This has nothing to do with Room and everything to do with filesystem permissions. You do not have the rights to access another app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), and that is where Room databases are stored.

Comment: @KannanRamamoorthy: The documentation discusses [internal storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#internal).